# DropDown not getting displayed with the npm run build

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, npm-run

Im very new to react and Im finding difficulty to solve the error. As im running my code with npm start, the dropdown is getting displayed but when I build my code using npm run build it is throwing an error. I need a help for this.

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
CountrySearch.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at CountrySearch.js:18

Country.js

```
class Country extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render () {
        let countries = this.props.state.countries;
        let optionItems = countries.map((country) =>
                <option key={country.COUNTRY_NAME}>{country.COUNTRY_NAME}</option>
            );

        return (
         <div>
             <select className="DrpDownSelectstyle">
                {optionItems}
             </select>
         </div>
        )
    }
}
```

CountrySearch.js

```
import Country from './Country';

class CountrySearch extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            countries: [],
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {
    let initialCountry = [];
    fetch('/wwsnr/webservices/pswebapi/api/GetCountries')
        .then(response => {
        return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
        initialCountry = json.map((country) => {
            return country
        });
        console.log(initialCountry);
        this.setState({
            countries: initialCountry,
        });
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <i><b>Search a country or region:</b></i>
            <div className="List">
                <Country state={this.state}/>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Your fetch call is responding with 404. `fetch('/wwsnr/webservices/pswebapi/api/GetCountries')`

Comment: Show us the scripts that are executed when running `npm start` and `npm run`